# How to deal with a manager who doesn't know what I do day to day?

Tags: manager

I am a software developer with a manager who I speak to once every two weeks at my 1 on 1s. They are for the most part about company culture, company policy, external projects, etc. None of it matters to me so I just sit there and nod. This is not the problem. It is just meant to set the context for how rarely I engage with him. Except for quarterly 1 on 1 events, nothing of significance is discussed in them.

However, a consistent problem has been that my boss is mostly giving me feedback based on what other people have said about me. He has no first hand insights dealing with me at all. All my feedback is good except from the project manager who complains about delays (even when I tell him I can't give estimates on things I have never done) and how things are unusable (because he asked a graphic designer to draw something that does not fit on a laptop screen).  There are no more experienced engineers at this company because management fired them all as they wanted to be remote.

I tell my manager all of this and he says that he doesn't know any of that so says it doesn't really matter. I feel like I may as well not speak at all.

For the meantime, I have stopped helping the project manager except when asked. Basically if he sends me a message, I will answer or if asked in a meeting I will answer, but I never contact him. Letting more of his spelling errors and bad requirements go public (but on time!) and such go live and he is taking flack for that so hopefully that erodes the value of his words to my boss as he starts to seem more like a screw up, but I want a more direct way to argue back with my boss.

Attack on both fronts!

Comment: Your boss doesn't bother you, and what exactly are you complaining about :) Just do your job as best as you could, try to mend relations with project manager if possible and that is that.

Comment: Bottom line: you need to communicate more with both your manager and the PM. No way around it.

Comment: Find a place that hires better engineers and learn from them?

Comment: Why are you not using the 1-on-1s to actually let your manager know what you do on a daily basis? You say you just sit there and nod along, that's a waste of both your and their time, isn't it? It's also your responsibility to use these moments to your advantage.

Comment: "He has no first-hand insights dealing with me at all." - So tell him what you have done in the past week, past month, and the past year before he has this discussion with you.

Comment: It might help to know how experienced (and/or how old) you are, how long you've been at this company, how long you've been in this situation, and whether it's common in this company.  — FWIW, while having a very hands-off manager isn't common, it doesn't have to be a bad thing IME, as long as you have an idea how you fit into the team/department and can manage yourself.  Some would say: make the most of it!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I can give meaningful advice without knowing more about your company structure and what the job of your manager actually is. Cause he is not managing you.

But if you have a biweekly meeting, my approach would be trying to use that time for something useful. Have you tried to prepare for those meetings with questions and queries? Is there something your manager can help you with? If your manager doesn't lead the meeting properly, maybe you should take the lead?

Have you tried to gauge why your manager picks the topics he discusses with you? He obviously thinks those topics are of concern for you. If you can't come up with a reason, ask him what the goal of your 1:1s is. I get the impression that you have severe communication problems. This is never fun.

Second front, the project manager: Please, please stop being passive aggressive. This is not helping and can get you fired quickly. A project manager has more leverage than a "lowly" software developer, especially if that developer thinks it's below him to build a proper relationship with his direct manager.